# Magento's cron.php: Persistent or not? Why putting it into cron?

Tags: linux, cron, magento

I have a question regarding **Magento**.

Apparently, to perform scheduled tasks within Magento, it needs to run a script called `cron.php`. Originally the script was triggered by an on-server crontab using the line `wget -O /dev/null http://www.example.com/cron12345.php`.

Unfortunately, due to some problems, we need to limit the life of the PHP FPM child processes to 300 seconds... and that murdered the PHP process running `cron.php`.

I tried running `cron.php` from CLI using the command `php -c /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini cron.php` and it *seemed* to work... but there were no output and the script just keeps running...

So my questions:

1. Is `cron.php` a one-shot script, or does it run until completion and needs to be invoked again?
2. If it needs to be regularly invoked (via cron), can I just add a crontab like the following:

> ```
> */15 * * * * cd /var/www/website && php -c /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini cron.php
> ```

Thank you for your kind assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It should finish, it can take some time especially if you didn't run it in a while.
   But generally it will finish. If it doesn't you'll need to check what is going on.
2. Yes, that is how this is generally done, see:
   http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

Comment: Omigosh, apparently I accidentally added "-d" before `cron.php` ... no wonder it seems to be just stuck there --__--  ... thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, you have declared the version of our module and the model class. The important part is the  element. I use it to configure the cron job. here you will find the full guide: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/setup-magento-cron-job/

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.